Responsibility of scientific theories?
I'm sorry this is more of a thought than a well-baked question, I'll try to add resources later.
One of (if not the) major contribution of science to society is converting its findings to actionable decisions, engineering, etc. Science is based on scientific and philosophical assumptions and interpretations. As part of a scientific research, there are some baked-in (either explicit or implicit) assumptions and worldviews that shape the research, and when producing the research paper the scientist is also in charge of interpreting its results. Hence, the actions that may spring from such research are deeply influenced by these thoughts and frameworks.
Easy examples might be theories of life and their influence on questions like abortion, theories of cognition and their influence on questions like artificial consciousness.
My point is, the scientist that publishes their research has included such assumptions/interpretations ("biases") and may potentially influence such questions that may have important ethical implications. Is there a sense (presumably legal but perhaps something else) of responsibility, and accountability, on the publishing of these thoughts? Or is the scientist simply a "knowledge producer" who has no responsibility on the kind (and quality) of the knowledge they produce?
I know that for certain fields, like social sciences, where there are ethical boards to approve research (especially when the research contains surveys which needs to be approved). I don't know if it applies to all fields.

Edit:
I've replaced "theories" with "assumptions", "interpretations". This might be a more appropriate terminology, they have the more subjective connotation I meant to use. I would like to emphasis though, that theories may very well be part of the scientist assumptions. The fact that it's a scientifically backed assumption, doesn't mean it isn't an assumption.

The ethical boards for reseach in social or medical science are more to make sure the experiment is conducted ethically, not the the results are interpreted "ethically" or are within an ethically approved larger theoretical system.

We need some ethical boards for how results are applied in society. So first we need some ethical boards for how to construct proper ethical boards. Maybe we could improve the political system while we're at it?

Does science have "baked-in" theories?
Kind of, but also not really.
One could say science relies on foundational claims, like induction and that the universe behaves in consistent ways (... although one might also argue whether that in particular is simply assumed, because it's tested with every scientific theory - if the universe didn't behave in consistent ways, predictions in science would broadly fail, which they don't).
Beyond that, any given scientific theory may be built on other scientific theories. The theories which have many theories built on top of them are also tested by each of those theories. If you try to build one theory on top of another theory that's flawed, the new theory may fail to generate correct predictions, so we'd reject the new theory, and we may also question the underlying theory.
If one believes one of those underlying theories are wrong, it shouldn't be too hard to construct an experiment to disprove it, and publish that. Disproving a well-established theory would get scientists all excited about all the new things they'd get to learn, and it'd probably get you a Nobel prize.
For the examples you mentioned: how we think of life and cognition is itself informed by scientific discovery, rather than the inverse. Although one might say that beliefs about souls and humanity's cosmic importance influenced science, and led to resistance towards certain scientific theories like heliocentrism (as exemplified by Galileo's conflict with the Church) and evolution. But eventually those biases were overcome and the evidence won out (although there are unfortunately still plenty of laypeople who don't accept evolution).
The people saying modern science is shaped by "baked-in theories" or presuppositions or such, or that it's dogmatic - those are usually the people arguing for various pseudosciences, unjustified claims, and conspiracy theories.
Do scientists have an ethical responsibility for what they research and publish?
Yes.
It's broadly accepted that it's bad to torture people for the sake of scientific discovery. The downside of not valuing and respecting human rights is far too great, and every life-changing discovery found in this way may include countless instances of torture with no upside, possibly used with questionable justification by someone who just likes torturing people. There are also usually more ethical means of getting results. Although society was still struggling to accept this a mere few decades ago, within the lifespan of many people who are still alive today.
Scientific ethics has been extending beyond that, to include e.g. research into which demographics are on average more intelligent than which others, because this achieves little more than validating bigotry, and may lead to more discrimination (especially by people who don't understand what "on average" means all that well), as well as hate crimes and eugenics. Those aren't things we want, so we oppose the research where a "positive" result does little more than produce those things, and a "negative" result tells us nothing all that useful (one might think research that disproves the claims bigotry is based on would be effective in fighting bigotry but history has shown that it absolutely isn't - people will keep repeating their bigoted claims even if you show them dozens of research papers that prove them wrong).
This is broadly based on the idea of consequentialism, which I might summarise with an example: Let's say you try to do a good thing by letting people drink freely from a river. This ends up contaminating the river, which is a water supply for a large number of people and thousand of people die. Now say you end up in that exact same scenario again, knowing the same action will result in the same outcome of contaminating the river and killing thousands. Consequentialism says it would be immoral to do the exact same thing again, because you know your actions, while they may be good-intentioned, will lead to thousands of people dying. You may instead e.g. syphon off some water from the river so people can drink from it without contaminating the river. The idea of consequentialism, as the name suggests, is to consider the likely consequences of an action, to determine whether it would be moral.
If we apply this to scientific research: we consider the likely outcomes of performing and publishing research about certain questions. If we see judge that those would have bad outcomes, we don't perform such research.
Scientific ethics does not include consideration of "baked-in theories" because that's not really a thing, as discussed above.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is an interesting question and I will try to answer it. But first we have to agree a bit on the word theory. In science a theory is an explanation that is supported by facts and is applicable to a broader scope. The word "theory" as used in the question is more of assumption / hypothesis. The science use of theory hence is different from everyday use of the word. We often set the quality mark on a theory that it has to have the property that it could be falsified. This is why, as example, Einsteins general relativity theory is still after a hundred years still a theory (there has been a lot of trying to falsify it, but none has succeded as of yet).
So, yes all scientist attacks research with a bunch of assumptions and often prejudices. The goal of the scientific method and peer review is to make sure that you as a reader can see these "flaws" clearly and understand what weight to put on them and on the published result as such.
But there are two further areas in the original question. The first is whether scientific results should be used for actual actions. And there I need to say that we need an ethical decision process. One extreme example: we know (from scientific research) that some diseases are inherited -- but this does not allow us to sterilize persons carrying these genes to stop them from getting children.
The second area is whether we should allow all kinds of research, or should we have censorship (self regulated or imposed) on what kind of questions science can ask? We do have a process for regulating what kind of experiments we find to be allowable which in my mind is a good thing. But in my mind, drawing the line on what questions we should avoid to investigate is very difficult.
And finally, does the scientist have responsibilities here? Yes I think. One is definitely to work hard to make sure that the scientific results are not misunderstood.

I like this answer, because I can resonate with what you're saying; but it feels a bit vague. You essentially raise questions back at me, and emphasize the difficulty of answering the question. I agree, I think it is difficult as well, and I think that you pinpoint important aspects of the question (and your standpoint on "theory" is correct, misuse of terminology on my part). But in the end you basically shared your thought on what should be. I'm trying to understand if there's any actual accountability for scientists. Or if academia has weigh in on the matter at all.

@YechiamWeiss. "... if there is any actual accountability for scientists" . In my opinion, basically no, if you by accountability means that correctly performed science can put you in prison. (Fraudulence can and sometimes is punishable). The accountability is subtler than that -- investigating the wrong things or reaching the wrong conclusions can get you excluded from the scientific community and hinder you from receiving grants for your research. The limits of wrong and right do change over time, the Roman Inquisition that sentenced Galileo is not (officially) in session today.

The problem for a scientist is often not so much the need to go beyond
a "knowledge producer" mindframe, but rather, on the contrary,
to resist temptations to let (true or imaginary) ethical agendas
influence one's scientific work.
One illustration is the recent "diversity trumps ability" controversy,
when Thompson challenged the statistics methodology used by Hong and
Page (which she felt was well-intentioned but misguided).  As Slaff
wrote,

"Thompson challenged the research by Hong and Page essentially
because, as she claims, her children were not learning anything in
school, due to what she feels are misplaced priorities in education."


"her children ... she feels" - nice anecdote and cool feelings, but that seems to have little if anything to do with the "diversity trumps ability" theorem that a diverse group of laypeople can outperform experts under certain circumstances.

Emphasis on "certain circumstances".

@keshlam Indeed. I wouldn't say diversity is a replacement for expertise, but it sure is a useful supplement. Especially when you get yourself a diverse group of experts, then you can potentially get the benefits of expertise, while also getting the benefits of a diversity of perspectives and ways of thinking.

Meanwhile, children learning things in school is pretty important. Each child, not the average of all the learning.

Is a blacksmith responsible for any murders committed with the knives they make?
That is, at its very core, your question. And there is no straightforward answer to this, it's a subjective point.
On one end of the spectrum: no, because knives are tools. They're used to cut your food, or help you with your daily work. Stabbing people is not the intended use, but it's unavoidable that a tool that helps you cut food also enables you to cut people (who, tongue in cheek, are also made of food).
On the other end of the spectrum, if the blacksmith designs a knife with properties that specifically enhance the ability to kill humans, and/or imbues it with properties that help conceal it (either from sight, or from metal detectors), then we can start considering that the blacksmith actively enabled the murdering of people using the knives they created.
I can't answer this question any further than pointing out both ends of the spectrum, and concluding that both of these (and myriad points inbetween) have some merit to them on an ethical level.

Some details in your question I want to address:

As part of a scientific research, there are some baked-in (either explicit or implicit) assumptions and worldviews that shape the research, and when producing the research paper the scientist is also in charge of interpreting its results

I'm not suggesting scientists are infallible, but the overall intention is to indicate biases an assumptions as best as possible, and peer reviews specifically are on the lookout for these.
Taking an oversimplified example, a mathematician must to some degree acknowledge that they base their findings on the assumption that 1+1=2, and if this were to not be the case, it would invalidate the basis for their subsequent claims.
It is not the responsibility of the researcher to avoid biases or assumptions; it is their responsibility to convey any and all known/suspected biases and assumptions.
From that point onwards, the onus is on whoever reads the scientific results to understand that the conclusions are based on these biases and assumptions, and that the conclusions cannot be upheld in confidence if any of these biases or assumptions end up being faulty.

Easy examples might be theories of life and their influence on questions like abortion

Other than the technical details of the medical procedure, the abortion discussion is not a scientific one, it's one of personal ethics.
People on both sides of this debate wrongly (whether conscious or subscious) use science as a justification for their stance, but both sides are not deriving their stance from the science, they're interpreting the science to favor their pre-existing opinion (or using science as a strawman to attack the other side's claims of scientific evidence, i.e. by discrediting the general concept of science it discredits any evidence that the opposing party might offer as evidence to their stance).
For obvious reasons, I'm not digging into the wrong and rights of either side of this debate. But the fact remains that the political debate here is not scientific in nature, and regardless of what scientific finding is presented, either camp is going to interpret it in their favor (either by leaning into it or using it as an entrypoint to attack science as a strawman to the actual debate).

[..] theories of cognition and their influence on questions like artificial consciousness.

This again isn't a particularly scientific question. Cognition and consciousness are philosophical constructs, not scientific ones.
However, that distinction is hard to deterministically point out until we fully understand the brain's inner workings, which is well ahead of where we currently are.
Contemporary discussion on artificial consciousness is often more an argument of either semantics (e.g. is ChatGPT AI or a very clever autocomplete?) or ethics (e.g. does using ChatGPT count as plagiarism?)

Your examples all boil down to the blacksmith's knife.
At its core, scientific enquiry tries its very best to avoid ulterior biases, so as to not let those ulterior interpretations become the driving agent for the scientific finding that is presented. The findings are presents with all biases and assumptions either removed, or explicitly listed to provide a framework for the findings.
We can argue where scientific findings are responsible for any biases that slip through even after peer review. However, the overall methodology of scientific enquiry and peer review tries to disavow itself from any ulterior biases or assumptions to the best of its ability.
Whether that suffices for someone to consider scientific results to be an accomplice to how it will be interpreted and applied; is a subjective topic of ethics.

"the abortion discussion is not a scientific one" -- there's a scientific issue of when the fetus becomes viable. Pre-Dobbs, that was the criteria for when abortion is allowed.


Responsibility of scientific theories?

The only responsibility of a scientific theory is transparency: a complete account of the process (including detailed reproducible experiments) that allows any scientist to understand the conclusion reached and to debate or support that conclusion.
